# Calculated Field With Conditions

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, conditional-statements, calculated-columns

I need your expertise on this problem I have. I have a Vehicle/Driver Inspection Database and I'm trying to create a Traffic Violation Point System, its a system when drivers commit certain traffic offences they will incur driving-offence points.

System: The points for violations that all occurred within the last 12 months of ONE ANOTHER are added together to calculate point total. If the accumulated points is reached 14 points driver is suspended the points will be REMOVED or minus 14 points after the suspension has been served.

Example:

Date of Offence - Number of Points

- Aug. 6, 2013 - 6
- Aug. 6, 2013 - 6
- Feb. 4, 2014 - 4
- Apr. 25, 2014 - 4
- Apr. 25, 2014 - 2
- May 8, 2014 - 2

Explanation:

On April 25, 2014 two offences incurred and from (Aug 6, 2013 - Apr. 25 2014) 14 points have accumulated (6 + 4 + 4) and suspension is carried out then 14 points is removed. The 2nd offence on Apr. 25, 2014 will be carried forward and added to May 8, 2014 points (total 4 points).

Below are DB Tables:

tbl_Driver

- DriverID
- Driver License
- FirstName
- LastName

tbl_Event

- EventID
- EventTime
- DriverID
- CarID

tbl_EventViolation

- EventViolatinID
- EventID
- ViolationID
- Status (1 = no, 2 = yes radio buttons)

tbl_Violation

- ViolationID
- ViolationName
- Points

tbl_ViolationClass

- ViolationClassID
- ClassName

I made an SQL Code but to sum the accumulated points only but not the whole condition. See below:

```
SELECT  a.DriverId, 
        a.DriverLicense, 
        a.FirstName + ' ' + a.LastName as DriverName,
        a.FirstName, 
        a.LastName, 
        a.DriverMobileNo1,         
        a.Notes, 
        SUM(a.Points) as TotalPoints                    
FROM
        (
         SELECT dbo.Event.EventTime, 
                dbo.Drivers.DriverID, 
                dbo.Drivers.DriverLicense,
                dbo.Drivers.FirstName,
                dbo.Drivers.LastName,
            dbo.Drivers.DriverMobileNo1, 
            dbo.Violation.ViolationName, 
            dbo.Violation.Points,
            dbo.Drivers.Notes
          FROM    dbo.Drivers INNER JOIN dbo.Event ON dbo.Drivers.DriverId = dbo.Event.DriverId      INNER JOIN
    dbo.EventViolation ON dbo.Event.EventId = dbo.EventViolation.EventId INNER JOIN
    dbo.Violation ON dbo.EventViolation.ViolationId = dbo.Violation.ViolationId INNER JOIN
    dbo.ViolationClass ON dbo.Violation.ViolationClassId = dbo.ViolationClass.ViolationClassID

    WHERE   dbo.EventViolation.Status = 2 
    AND dbo.ViolationClass.ClassName Like 'C' 
    AND dbo.Violation.ViolationName Not Like 'LOAD NOT CORRECTLY RESTRAINED'
    AND dbo.Violation.ViolationName Not Like 'DRIVING WITHOUT UAE LICENSE' 

    ) as a
GROUP BY a.DriverId, a.DriverLicense, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.DriverMobileNo1, a.Notes
ORDER BY Points desc
```

Please anyone try to modify the code to work on the conditions set above

Thank you for your time. Looking forward for the solution.

Comment: You've detailed out your specs very well, but you have not asked a succinct question. Are you trying to get total points for the driver?

Comment: Additionally, I see that there are commas missing from your select statement that would make it not compile.  Perhaps you could create a working [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to help clarify your code.

Comment: @paqogomez yes total points of the driver. This is a working code, I believe only one comma is missing, its in Inner Query "dbo.Violation.Points". Thanks for the immediate response

Comment: I don't see an infraction date anywhere in your schema description or query.

Comment: @DanBracuk is correct, your `tbl_EventViolation` table needs a infraction date column in order to know when the year is up.

Comment: @DanBracuk apologies, I mistakenly forgot to put in the tbl_Event the field EventTime